# How to work with signin manager with jwt token

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm in trouble to work with jwt token using identity framework.

```
public async Task<Response> LoginAsync()
{
    SignInResult result = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync("jwt", "12345", true);
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what is the exact trouble you are facing?

Comment: I would like to use signin manager with jwt authentication